# Unable to catch the exception from selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have written some code which deals with C# reflections and selenium to automate the build process of a URL.

But I am unable to catch the exception. What I did is , I exported into .html format from selenium IDE. and parsed and it automatically calls the function related to it from c# code.

but I am unable to catch it. I need help in this regard? Any guesses why it is unable to catch the exception..

I am using Visual Studio Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.

And the code is as follows.

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using Selenium;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.IO;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        public ISelenium selenium;

        public void SetupTest()
        {
            selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "URL");
            selenium.Start();
        }

        //[TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                selenium.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        public void myFun(string file) 
        {
             bool flag = false;
             string targetString = "", valueString = "", commandString = "";
             string subString1, subString2;
             HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode commandNode=null;
             HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode targetNode=null;
             HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode valueNode=null;

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

                doc.Load(file);
                doc.OptionCheckSyntax = true;
                doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
                doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
                doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
                doc.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.Default;

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
                foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
                {
                    commandNode = row.SelectSingleNode("td[1]");
                    commandString = commandNode.InnerHtml.ToString();

                    subString1 = commandString.Substring(0, 1);

                    subString1 = subString1.ToUpper();
                    subString2 = commandString.Substring(1, commandString.Length - 1);

                    commandString = subString1 + subString2;

                     targetNode = row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]");

                    if (targetNode != null)
                    {
                        targetString = targetNode.InnerHtml.ToString();

                        if (targetString.Length == 0)
                        {
                            targetNode = null;
                        }
                    }

                   valueNode = row.SelectSingleNode("td[3]");
                    if (valueNode != null)
                    {
                        valueString = valueNode.InnerHtml.ToString();

                        if (valueString.Length == 0)
                        {
                            valueNode = null;
                        }

                    }

                    MethodInfo SeleniumMethod = typeof(ISelenium).GetMethod(commandString);

                    if (SeleniumMethod == null)
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine(" \n NULL " + commandString);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (targetNode == null && valueNode == null)
                        continue;
                    if (targetNode != null && valueNode != null)
                        {
                            String[] SeleniumArgs = new String[2];
                            SeleniumArgs[0] = targetNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
                            SeleniumArgs[1] = valueNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
                            try
                            {
                                SeleniumMethod.Invoke(selenium, SeleniumArgs);
                            }

                            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
                            {
                            }

                            catch (Selenium.SeleniumException se)
                            {
                                flag = true;
                                string lines = "\n Selenium Exception: Caught an exception while executing the script : " + file + "  with the command : " + commandNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + "  and the  XPath is: " + targetNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + " and the value is : " + valueNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + " and the exception is as follows :  ";
                                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(lines);
                                    writer.Flush();
                                    writer.Close();

                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {

                                flag = true;
                                string lines = "\n  Exception: Caught an exception while executing the script : " + file + "  with the command : " + commandNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + "  and the  XPath is: " + targetNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + " and the value is : " + valueNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + " and the exception is as follows :  ";
                                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(lines);
                                    writer.Flush();
                                    writer.Close();

                                }

                           }

                        }

                        else if (targetNode != null && valueNode == null)
                        {
                            String[] SeleniumArgs = new String[1];
                            SeleniumArgs[0] = targetNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
                            SeleniumMethod.Invoke(selenium, SeleniumArgs);

                        }
                    else if (valueNode != null)
                    {
                        String[] SeleniumArgs = new String[1];
                        SeleniumArgs[0] = valueNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
                        SeleniumMethod.Invoke(selenium, SeleniumArgs);
                    }

                }// end of for

            string line = "\n Script executed successfully ";
            if (flag == false)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class TestProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                p.SetupTest();

                string file = @"1.html";
                p.myFun(file);
                p.TeardownTest();
           }
            catch  { }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception are you looking to catch? You have included a lot of catch blocks, some are empty blocks and some trap exceptions. But you say you are not able to catch...so which one are you targetting?

Comment: Can you please tell me which exception block you are expecting to catch. Or put a break point at starting of your main method and then step through your code. See where it is throwing you error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to catch the exception in your `Main()` method, you need to bubble your exceptions up in your `myFun` method. At the moment you are drowning any exceptions in your `myFun` method.

e.g.

```
try
{
    SeleniumMethod.Invoke(selenium, SeleniumArgs);
}
catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
{
    throw; //make this bubble up to the calling method.
}
catch (Selenium.SeleniumException se)
{
    flag = true;
    string lines = "\n Selenium Exception: Caught an exception while executing the script : " + file + "  with the command : " + commandNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + "  and the  XPath is: " + targetNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + " and the value is : " + valueNode.InnerHtml.ToString() + " and the exception is as follows :  ";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(lines);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
    throw se; //bubble up to calling method
}
//etc...
```

Comment: It says :-                                             Selenium.SeleniumException was unhandled by user code
  Message=ERROR: Option with label 'ApplicationLoad' not found
  Source=ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core
  StackTrace:
       at Selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.DoCommand(String command, String[] args) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\Selenium.Core\HttpCommandProcessor.cs:line 98
       at Selenium.DefaultSelenium.Select(String selectLocator, String optionLocator) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\Selenium.Core\DefaultSelenium.cs:line 567
  InnerException:

Comment: This suggests the problem is with your `SetupTest()` method. Try explicitly handling a Selenium.SeleniumException in your `SetupTest()` method.